# Classifier predictions are unreliable, is that because my GMM classifier is not trained correctly?

Tags: python, machine-learning, speech-recognition, mfcc

I'm training two GMM classifiers, each for one label, with MFCC values.
I concatenated all the MFCC values of a class and fitted into a classifier.
And for each classifier I sum the probability of its label's probability.

```
def createGMMClassifiers():
    label_samples = {}
    for label, sample in training.iteritems():
        labelstack = np.empty((50,13))
        for feature in sample:
            #debugger.set_trace()
            labelstack = np.concatenate((labelstack,feature))
        label_samples[label]=labelstack
    for label in label_samples:
        #debugger.set_trace()
        classifiers[label] = mixture.GMM(n_components = n_classes)
        classifiers[label].fit(label_samples[label])
    for sample in testing['happy']:
        classify(sample)
def classify(testMFCC):
    probability = {'happy':0,'sad':0}
    for name, classifier in classifiers.iteritems():
        prediction = classifier.predict_proba(testMFCC)
        for probforlabel in prediction:
            probability[name]+=probforlabel[0]
    print 'happy ',probability['happy'],'sad ',probability['sad']

    if(probability['happy']>probability['sad']):
        print 'happy'
    else:
        print 'sad'
```

But my results does not seems to be consistent and I find it hard to believe it is because of the RandomSeed=None state since all the predictions is often are the same label for all test data, but each run it often gives the exact opposites(See Output 1 and output 2).

So my question is, am I doing something obviously wrong while training my classifier?

Output 1:

```
happy  123.559202732 sad  122.409167294
happy

happy  120.000879032 sad  119.883786657
happy

happy  124.000069307 sad  123.999928962
happy

happy  118.874574047 sad  118.920941127
sad

happy  117.441353421 sad  122.71924156
sad

happy  122.210579428 sad  121.997571901
happy

happy  120.981752603 sad  120.325940128
happy

happy  126.013713257 sad  125.885047394
happy

happy  122.776016525 sad  122.12320875
happy

happy  115.064172476 sad  114.999513909
happy
```

Output 2:

```
happy  123.559202732 sad  122.409167294
happy

happy  120.000879032 sad  119.883786657
happy

happy  124.000069307 sad  123.999928962
happy

happy  118.874574047 sad  118.920941127
sad

happy  117.441353421 sad  122.71924156
sad

happy  122.210579428 sad  121.997571901
happy

happy  120.981752603 sad  120.325940128
happy

happy  126.013713257 sad  125.885047394
happy

happy  122.776016525 sad  122.12320875
happy

happy  115.064172476 sad  114.999513909
happy
```

Earlier I asked a relevant question and got a correct answer. I'm providing the link below.

[Having different results every run with GMM Classifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38032454/having-different-results-every-run-with-gmm-classifier/38057895#38057895)

Edit:
Added main function which collects the data and splits into training and testing

```
def main():
    happyDir = dir+'happy/'
    sadDir = dir+'sad/'
    training["sad"]=[]
    training["happy"]=[]
    testing["happy"]=[]
    #TestSet
    for wavFile in os.listdir(happyDir)[::-1][:10]:
        #print wavFile
        fullPath = happyDir+wavFile
        testing["happy"].append(sf.getFeatures(fullPath))
    #TrainSet
    for wavFile in os.listdir(happyDir)[::-1][10:]:
        #print wavFile
        fullPath = happyDir+wavFile
        training["happy"].append(sf.getFeatures(fullPath))
    for wavFile in os.listdir(sadDir)[::-1][10:]:
        fullPath = sadDir+wavFile
        training["sad"].append(sf.getFeatures(fullPath))
    #Ensure the number of files in set
    print "Test(Happy): ", len(testing['happy'])
    print "Train(Happy): ", len(training['happy'])
    createGMMClassifiers()
```

Edit 2:
Changed the code according to the answer. Still having similar kind of inconsistent results.

Answer (score 0):

For classification tasks it's important to tune parameter given to the classifier, also a large number of classification algorithm follow chose theory, witch means if you change some parameter of the model briefly, you may get some huge different results. Also it's important to use different algorithms and not just use one algorithm for all classification tasks,

For this problem, you can try different classification algorithm to test that your data is good, and try different parameter with different values for each classifier, then you can determined that where is the problem.

One alternative way is to use Grid Search to explore and tune best parameter for specific classifier, read this: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion! I'll check the link as soon as possible after I get meaningful results this particular classification algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has not much sense, you recreate classifier for every new training sample.

Correct code scheme for training should look about this:

```
label_samples = {}
classifiers = {}

# First we collect all samples per label into array of samples
for label, sample in samples:
     label_samples[label].concatenate(sample)

# Then we train classifier on every label data
for label in label_samples:
     classifiers[label] = mixture.GMM(n_components = n_classes)
     classifiers[label].fit(label_samples[label])
```

Your decoding code is ok.

Comment: concatenating empty dictionary value raises error.
Will using label_samples[label] = np.concatenate(sample,label_samples[label]) achieves the same result?

Comment: Edited the question with updated code, still experiencing similar kind of inconsistent results.